# Prevent Breaking of Negative Numbers

Tags: html, css

My HTML page contain tables with many negative numbers, like &#8211;0.25 .  8211 is the n-dash. Because my document is supposed to become epub2 eventually, javascript is not allowed.  only xhtml+css.

Unfortunately, both ebook readers and the print function in Chrome think that it is a reasonable idea to line-break a negative number between the en-dash and the zero, even when there is a space before and/or after, e.g., in a table.

I need a "non-breaking" en-dash?  there are non-breakable spaces, after all, too.  Or is there a way to instruct css never to break such negative numbers anywhere throughout the entire document? (I doubt this one, but just had to ask.)

of course, I can wrap each negative number into a span to prevent breaking, but this is quite painful.  literally, by the time I am all done, my number --0.25 would have to become <span class="nobreak">&#8211;0.25</span>.  (joke: it's almost like a DOS 10x amplification attack, with 4 chars becoming 40 characters, all because I want to have negative numbers.)

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: An en-dash is not a minus, even if it looks like one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent negative numbers from breaking by using the proper MINUS SIGN “−” (U+2212). In
text rendering, browsers, ebook readers, and other software often treat EN DASH as well as HYPHEN-MINUS (the common Ascii hyphen) as allowing a line break after it, even when immediately followed by a digit. According to Unicode line-breaking rules, MINUS SIGN should not cause this, and most software nowadays plays by those rules in this issue.

However, since some software on iOS platforms has been reported to behave differently, you may still want to use CSS to prevent line breaks as mentioned in the question. However, it is often possible to use simpler markup or even not use any added markup. Specifically, when a number is the only content of a cell, you can write just e.g. `<td class="nobreak">&minus;0.25</td>` without an added `span` element. And at the extreme, if all data cells in all tables on a page contain just numbers, you could just use `<td>&minus;0.25</td>` in HTML and `td { white-space: nowrap }` in CSS. In less extreme cases, you can probably use suitable CSS selectors like `td:nth-child(3)` without resorting to `class` attributes and class selectors.

In HTML, you can write MINUS SIGN as `&minus;` if you have difficulties in typing the character or if you wish to make it clear to anyone reading the HTML source that MINUS SIGN is used.

Comment: &minus; is not the same as the Unicode hyphen &#8209; and does not prevent line breaking.

Comment: @danebez, nobody mentioned the Unicode hyphen before, and MINUS SIGN does prevent line breaking in all browsers that I tested; please specicy the browsers where you have observed that it does not prevent breaking.

Comment: Indeed not, which is why I mentioned it. Google Chrome for Mac version 34.0.1847.131.

Comment: I don’t see *why* you mentioned the Unicode hyphen, since it is clearly *not* a character that should be used as a minus sign. The Ascii hyphen, i.e. HYPHEN-MINUS, is ambiguous, but the Unicode HYPHEN has been intentionally disambiguated to mean only punctuation hyphen. Regarding Chrome on Mac, can anyone confirm the observation? E.g., does `&minus;42` ever get divided so that the minus sign is at the end of a line? If this really happens, then a `span` wrapper would be needed.

Comment: I _mentioned_ it because if you _use_ it, it will _not_ line break. Therefore, if you substitute your _minus_ characters for it, it will be one solution. And since you probably _can't_ tell the difference visually between the two hyphens, it is a viable solution. You _imply_ that using the minus sign is a solution, but it's not on Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Confirmed that this DOES NOT work in Chrome 111.0.5563.64 or Safari on iOS 16.3.1.