# wkhtmltopdf breaking line with negative values

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf on a Ubuntu server. The problem I have been facing is that negative big numbers break lines. I saw this thread: [Prevent Breaking of Negative Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061036/prevent-breaking-of-negative-numbers). My values are read directly from the database, and differently from this guy I don't add a hyphen.

#### Negative numbers:

[image]

#### Positive:

[image]

This is after I upgraded to version wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt). On version 0.9.9, which I had been using I had no problem with PDF generation. I upgraded because in Django, Views which inherited the PDF class from `django-wkhtmltopdf` would give an error code 1, not generating PDF.

PDFs are generated through command line:

```
command = 'xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf --footer-right "[page]/[topage]" {s} {o}'.format(
            s=html_file.name,
            o=target.name
        )
```

I tried to add `--zoom 0.5` as a parameter to that command, but only made the PDF worse. Half of the text got cut out off the page and can't be read.

Answer (score 1):

Try with replacing minus sign with `&minus;` html entity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After much time of investigation, I discovered that you can solve the issue if you put min-width (css) in the column (td).

You must be sure that the min-width is enought for the value of td.

After that all work like a charm!

Good Look!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a CSS rule, that says, the text should not wrap.

```
td.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```